# changing label text in master page from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to change text of label in master page from another page. In master page, code of label which I want to change text is like this:

```
 <div align="right" style="padding-right: 15px">
    <asp:Label ID="labelIsim" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
          ForeColor="White" Font-Italic="True" >labelname</asp:Label>
         <br />
  </div>
```

I write a code something like this:

```
  Label m = (Label)Master.FindControl("labelIsim");
  string yname = Session["name"].ToString() + " " + Session["lastname"].ToString();
  m.Text = yname;
  m.Visible = true;
```

But text of label remained same.Program didn't give any error.It can find the right label, in m.Text; I see the right values but I couldn't see the changes in the browser.where is the mistake ? thanks..

EDIT:

Actually this code changes the text but when I go another page, text of label returns default value. How can I prevent this?

Comment: In which event of page life cycle, do you write the above code?

Comment: when user presses the login button. In button click event.

Answer (score 2):

You should store it's state in viewstate and then take the values you store in viewstate and set those in the load event of the label.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's because you have the string `labelname` in your markup. Unless you re-run your code in every child page it will go back to default.